# Why rsync found files who has vanished on exfat synology?

Tags: rsync, synology, exfat

I try to transfer some files from an external hard drive in exfat to my synology Nas using rsync using the usb connection.

During the transfert `rsync` found files who have vanished when it's time to copy them.

But these files are not visible with `ls` or with the windows explorer.

These files looks to me move somewhere else or been deleted in the past.

I run on windows `chkdisk \f` on the drive and no error has been found.

I don't know why `rsync` see files that doesn't exist anymore when building the list.
Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The Synology support for ExFat is just broken and in some cases, it can show files in the wrong place. When this happens the file cannot be accessed and ls will report a lot of error before showing you the wrong list of files